# Should I store QR Code as a 'text' or an 'image'?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, qr-code

#### Background Story

I am learning to make a simple application using Firestore. This app gets data from Excel and would later be transformed into JSON and stored in Firestore. Examples of the data would be something like this.

```
ajskdlfajsldkfj: { // <- example firestore reference, and will be the QR Code
  name: 'Item 1',
  description: 'A really cool item'
}
```

Then, in the client application, I would just show the user a list of items, and they could see the QR Code. And the user would be able to share the QR code with others.

#### What I want to know

I wanted to know what is the best practice for showing QR Code, since QR Codes can be generated at the time user request in the client application. However, I'm not pretty sure about it.

**Back to the question**
1. Should I just create a QR Code image then store it in the server OR just store the value in the server?
2. What would be the **pro** and **cons** of saving QR Code as a 'text' and an 'image' in terms of performance, security, or price?

Thank you.

Comment: are you using angular for front end?

Comment: I have not done any testing to back up my ideas, but my intuition would be that it would require less storage and be quicker to search as a text than as an image, and as you can generate the image readily whenever you need it, I would be inclined to opt for textual storage. Always happy to be corrected if anyone knows better.

Comment: I was recently working on a project for both generating and scanning a qr code with using angular and firebase. I stored the value as a text since scan gives me a string so I can compare the values easily. Also, angular has a plugin for converting strings to qr codes with just one element in the html. In my personal opinion, handling images not that easy sometimes.

Comment: If you can regenerate the QR code on demand, why not just store the data it contains? That should be much simpler to handle, and take up much less space as well.

Comment: At everyone above, yeah, that's actually what I thought. Storing 'text' sounds like a good idea. I was just wondering wheter it's a good practice and want to know wheter someone had the same thought as mine too. (Just to make sure) **P.S.** I use VueJS, but I think that doesn't matter right?

Comment: language shouldn't matter so long as there is a plugin etc for converting text to image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion,

Pros for storing as text:

- easy maintenance since you can see the value you can validate it
  without the need of converting
- for the first time you don't need to convert the text to image first
  to store it
- depending on the front end you are using, a plugin can convert it for
  you so you don't need to code

Pros for storing as image:

- don't need to convert the text to image to display

for both:

- both of them needs converting at some point
- either way  they in the db and if anyone can access them they will be compromised (unless you are going to encode the text). So, for security important part is setting firestore rules to prevent unauthorized access.

Comment: `(unless you are going to encode the text).`, Ah, that's a good point! I almost forgot about security.